# Macwire, wireWith and implicit parameters

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, macwire

`wireWith` seems to have some issues with resolving implicit parameters.

Minimal example:

```
import com.softwaremill.macwire._

object A {
  def props(x: Int)(implicit y: String): A = new A(x)
}

class A(x: Int)(implicit y: String) {
   val sum: String = s"$x + $y"
}

object App {
   def main(): Unit = {
     val xVal: Int = 3
     implicit val yVal: String = "5"

     // val aInstance = wire[A] // works
     // val aInstance = A.props(xVal) // works
     val aInstance: A = wireWith(A.props _) // compile error

     println(aInstance.sum)
  }
}

App.main()
```

Error:

```
Error:(21, 33) type mismatch; found   : Int required: String
    val aInstance: A = wireWith(A.props _)
                           ^
```

If `implicit` is ommitted at `yVal`, it complains about missing implicit:

```
Error:(18, 36) could not find implicit value for parameter y: String 
    val aInstance: A = wireWith(A.props _) // compile error
                              ^
```

This is a simplified example though - in my production code i try to wire Actor props:

```
object Actor {
    def props
        (dependency: Dependency, refreshInterval: FiniteDuration @@ CacheRefreshInterval)
        (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Props =
            Props(new Actor(dependency, refreshInterval))
}

// DI container
protected implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext
protected lazy val dependency: Dependency = wire[Dependency]
protected lazy val refreshInterval = 2.second.taggedWith[CacheRefreshInterval]
protected lazy val actorProps: Props @@ ActorProps = actorwireWith(Actor.props _)
```

and get different compile error:

```
too many arguments for method props: (implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)akka.actor.Props
```

I've tried making implicit parameter explicit and it worked just fine, except it's a bit against usual practice of passing execution context implicitly.

Am I doing something wrong or is it an issue in macwire?

Issue in Github: https://github.com/adamw/macwire/issues/125

Comment: I think this is a bug in MacWire; Btw - why would you pass an EC to the actor? You can use the one from the actor system, unless you need a dedicated EC for some work?

Comment: Thanks! I know I can use akka system's execution context, but (1) I just prefer to leave some way to easily override it if necessary because (2) that actor operates on some Future-based APIs and I might want to run them separately from actor system context (those APIs are mostly IO-bound as they call external services, while an actor is mostly CPU-bound)

Comment: @adamw And thanks for confirming - I'll submit it as an issue through github than

Answer (score 0):

If you were using `wireWith(A.props _)` as a workaround for macwire's inability to wire actors when their constructor are using implicit parameters (see macwire [issue 121](https://github.com/adamw/macwire/issues/121)), you could switch to macwire 2.3.1 and wire your actors using `wireActor[A]`, `wireAnonymousActor[A]` or `wireProps[A]`. [issue 121](https://github.com/adamw/macwire/issues/121) was fixed in macwire 2.3.1.